# AngularJS Assoc Array Foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

In this AngularJS associative array (array of key,value pairs), ng-repeat is not functioning properly. What's wrong?

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.list = [];

    $scope.processSomeData = function(){
        $scope.list["testKey"]={};
        $scope.list["testKey"]["test"]="Test value";
    };
    $scope.processSomeData();
}

<div ng-app>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in list">
          {{key}}
          {{value.test}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ebZkg/

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your "associative array" should be an Javascript **Object** and not a Javascript Array. You cannot use js Arrays in AngularJS for key, value pairs/maps.

Change your `list` to an Object and it will work:

```
$scope.list = {};
```

Comment: On a side note, is there any way to sort by key?

Comment: There's not a direct way to do it, but it's possible. You would need to create your own sort function and most probably duplicate the data. Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/ebZkg/1/

Comment: There is actually, you can just use orderBy (actually I just realized that's what you said anyway)